# WPF bind to property of the ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, binding

I've written a code example below:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>Appointments today</TextBlock>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Appointments}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <controls:CalendarMonthDayEventsItemsPanel OutsideViewportCount="..." />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock>+</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ......}" /> <!-- Should show number of items in ItemsControl that are outside view, using  CalendarMonthDayEventsItemsPanel.OutsideViewportCount -->
        <TextBlock>more items</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

</StackPanel>
```

I Created a custom Panel, the `CalendarMonthDayEventsItemsPanel`, and I use that panel as the itemspanel of the `ItemsControl`. In the panel's layout code, I determine how many items (panel childs) are outside the bounds of the panel. The property `OutsideViewportCount` contains the number of items that are outside of the visible bounds of the `CalendarMonthDayEventsItemsPanel`.

Now I want to show the value of `OutsideViewportCount` in a `TextBlock` that's below the `ItemsControl`.

This means I have to create some kind of binding, but everything I tried doesn't work.
Does someone have a solution or a better approach to achieve the same result?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you can make use of `Tag` property of `ItemsPanel` to relay the value of ItemsPanel as a workaround.

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="A"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Appointments}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:CalendarMonthDayEventsItemsPanel OutsideViewportCount="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=Tag, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    ...
</ItemsControl>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock>+</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=A, Path=Tag, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <TextBlock>more items</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: It **is** a workaround. But it's more like a quick fix.

Comment: So why not give the `CalendarMonthDayEventsPanel` a  dependency property to hold this value and bind to that? Your layout code code set it and the `TextBlock` could bind to it.

Comment: @user2190492 Yes, it is the easiest "some kind of binding" what you need.

Comment: @Joe I am not sure how to directly bind to a dependency property inside ItemsPanelTemplate. Could you show an example?

Comment: Give the panel element an `x:Name` attribute, like @emoacht did for the `ItemsControl` in his template.  Then, bind using the `ElementName` form of specifying the source, just as his example did.  The only difference would be that a) you would need to add the  `DependencyProperty` to your panel class and b) would need to use its name instead of the `ItemsControl`'s.  It's a lot of work for not very much.  You're better off just using the `Tag` property as he @emoacht suggests

Comment: @Joe Thanks for explanation but have you tried it? I have tried it but `x:Name` of the panel inside ItemsPanelTemplate seems not be able to be accessed from outside.

Comment: No I haven't tried it. I would have expected it to work but since the panel is in the template, maybe not.  You could obviously bind to the `ItemsControl,` with a path to its panel, cast to your panel type and *then* get the custom `DependencyProperty`.  But at this point, the word "overkill" becomes inadequate to describe how useless this is.  I suggest just using `Tag` on the `ItemsControl` @emoacht suggested.  Seriously this sort of, "I-need-a-property-to-bind-to-hold-something-arbitrary" situation is exactly what the `Tag` is meant for.  It's a quick fix yes but it can be a permanent one

Comment: @Joe Thanks for confirmation. I can think of a numbr of ways for binding but this is the easiest one.